# Difference between namespace Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls and Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I wish to learn how to build native WPF desktop app, by applying some modern UI (Like navigation view) from UWP.

However, I'm getting rather confused, with same class name, but different namespace

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview?view=winrt-19041 (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview?view=winui-2.4 (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls)

I was wondering, which is which, and which I should use in my WPF project?

Thanks.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/998

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` is the namespace used in the [WinUI](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/) library.

`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` is the namespace of the native controls that are included in Windows.

Microsoft is currently in the progress of breaking out the entire interface layer that contains the modern Windows controls and styles from the operating system into a separate WinUI 3 framework that will ship later this year.

So to answer your question about which one to use, `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` is the namespace to use going forward.